# Homology union three subspaces.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Consider the following subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$:
$$A=\{(x,y,z):x^{2}+y^{2}=1, z\in[-1,1] \}$$
$$B=\{(x,y,z): x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 1, z\in\{-1,0,1\} \}$$
$$C=\{(0,0,z):z\in[-1,1]\}.$$
Let $X=A\cup B\cup C$.
How can I compute the singular homology groups $H_{k}(X)$ for $k\geq 0$?

Comment: Have you made a picture of the thing? Can you describe it?

Comment: There are a ton of ways to do this.  You could triangulate it.  You could find nice contractible subspaces to mod out to make the space easier to understand.  You could break it into simpler pieces and use Mayer-Vietoris.  Have you tried any of these?

Comment: Do not vandalize a question you post to render it nonsense, after having received any answer(s).  Upon submitting your question to MSE, you relinquish ownership of the post. It is ***not*** yours to destroy.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a picture.
2. Try to see if the set deformation retracts onto a simpler set.
3. Decompose the simpler set into simplices glued to each other along their boundary (exhibit a CW-complex structure).
4. Turn the gluing information from 3. into a cellular chain complex.
5. Compute the (co)homology.